# Append increment number to duplicate item in array of objects

Tags: ruby

There are duplicate items in the array. I want to append an incremental number to such items. For example:

Input:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "john"},
  {id: 2, name: "Man"},
  {id: 3, name: "Man"},
  {id: 4, name: "john"},
  {id: 5, name: "kind"},
  {id: 6, name: "nova"},
  {id: 7, name: "kind"},
  {id: 8, name: "fred"},
  {id: 9, name: "fred"},
  {id: 10, name: "john"}
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "john-1"},
  {id: 2, name: "Man-1"},
  {id: 3, name: "Man-2"},
  {id: 4, name: "john-2"},
  {id: 5, name: "kind-1"},
  {id: 6, name: "nova"},
  {id: 7, name: "kind-2"},
  {id: 8, name: "fred"},
  {id: 9, name: "monk"},
  {id: 10, name: "john-3"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the input data can be huge, is there any way to mutate the same object and find only duplicate to reduce the latency and memory

Something like this would work:

```
input
  .group_by { |item| item[:name] }
  .reject { |_name, entries| entries.count == 1 }
  .each do |_name, entries|
    entries.each.with_index(1) do |entry, index|
      entry[:name] << "-#{index}"
    end
  end
```

It groups the items by their `:name` key and rejects those with only 1 entry. It then traverses the remaining groups (i.e. with 2 or more entries) and appends the 1-bases index to each entry's name.

Afterwards, `input` will be:

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"john-1"},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"Man-1"},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"Man-2"},
 {:id=>4, :name=>"john-2"},
 {:id=>5, :name=>"kind-1"},
 {:id=>6, :name=>"nova"},
 {:id=>7, :name=>"kind-2"},
 {:id=>8, :name=>"fred-1"},
 {:id=>9, :name=>"fred-2"},
 {:id=>10, :name=>"john-3"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some quick example with given input:

```
input
  .group_by { |value| value[:name] }
  .values
  .select { |x| x.map.with_index(1) { |y, i| p y[:name] = "#{y[:name]}-#{i}" } }
  .flatten
```

And thats the output:

```
[{:id=>1, :name=>"john-1"},
 {:id=>4, :name=>"john-2"},
 {:id=>10, :name=>"john-3"},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"Man-1"},
 {:id=>3, :name=>"Man-2"},
 {:id=>5, :name=>"kind-1"},
 {:id=>7, :name=>"kind-2"},
 {:id=>6, :name=>"nova-1"},
 {:id=>8, :name=>"fred-1"},
 {:id=>9, :name=>"fred-2"}]
```

Group by will group input by duplicated names. I don't know if you tried anything but this is something that you can start work with and improve.

Comment: if there is no duplicate found, we no need to append integer, in the above input instead of "nova-1" can be just "nova"

Comment: you can add condition to `map.with_index` - `if x.size > 1` and you get `nova`

Comment: It rearranges the items (

Comment: you can sort by key ID. Or do this line by line, for example: `input.each_with_object([]) { |el, obj| val = (obj.select{|k| k[:name].split('-')[0] == el[:name]}); z = val.size.zero? ? 1 : val.size+1; obj << { id: el[:id], name: "#{el[:name]}-#{z}" } }`  (this oneliner would be more readable in multiline)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to mutate the same input and incremented the values in name string

```
orders = [{:id=>2, :name=>"Man"}, {:id=>3, :name=>"Man"}, {:id=>8, :name=>"fred"}, {:id=>9, :name=>"fred"},{:id=>5, :name=>"kindaa"}, {:id=>1, :name=>"john"}, {:id=>4, :name=>"john"}, {:id=>10, :name=>"john"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"kinda"}, {:id=>5, :name=>"kind"}, {:id=>7, :name=>"kind"}, {:id=>6, :name=>"nova"}, {:id=>11, :name=>"nova"}] 
    counter = 1
    orders.each_with_index do |order, index|
    if index < orders.length - 1
    if order[:name] == orders[index + 1][:name]
      orders[index][:name] = orders[index][:name].to_s + "-#{counter}"
      counter = counter + 1
    else
      orders[index][:name] = orders[index][:name].to_s + "-#{counter}" if counter > 1
      counter = 1
    end
    else
      orders[index][:name] = orders[index][:name].to_s + "-#{counter}" if counter > 1
    end
    end
    puts orders
```

> Output:

```
{:id=>2, :name=>"Man-1"}
{:id=>3, :name=>"Man-2"}
{:id=>8, :name=>"fred-1"}
{:id=>9, :name=>"fred-2"}
{:id=>5, :name=>"kindaa"}
{:id=>1, :name=>"john-1"}
{:id=>4, :name=>"john-2"}
{:id=>10, :name=>"john-3"}
{:id=>5, :name=>"kinda"}
{:id=>5, :name=>"kind-1"}
{:id=>7, :name=>"kind-2"}
{:id=>6, :name=>"nova-1"}
{:id=>11, :name=>"nova-2"}
```